# JS exstract part of URL from multiple form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, url, split

I have a form that has multiple fields all with the same class. These are populated with URL's that follow the same structure. I am trying to extract the same section from each URL. So far var res = x.split('/')[5]; will achieve this but only for the first URL. I can also use var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example") to change all the url's but I cannot find the correct way to combine both of these function. so far my code looks like this:

```
script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example").innerHTML;
var res = x.split('/')[5];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].innerHTML = res;
}
}
</script>
```

I have looked around but can't find a solution that fits. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `var x = document.querySelectorAll(".example").innerHTML;` querySelectorAll does not have an innerHTML method since it is an HTML Collection. You would need to loop over the collection.

Comment: Given that you are trying to work with a url some how, I would be curious to see an example of the html.  I'm curious if `.innerHTML` is also the wrong property.

Comment: We need HTML to work with. Also all the more helpful if you can include usable code inside a snippet. I bet we can write you a nice regex that will accomplish what you want. Don't forget to clearly specify 1) what the input is; 2) what output you're getting and 3) what the output should be.

Answer (score 1):

So loop over the HTML Collection, this is making assumptions based on code.

```js
// Find all the elements
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".example")
// loop over the collection
elems.forEach(function (elem) {
   // reference the text of the element and split it
   var txt = elem.innerHTML.split("/")[5]
   // replace the text
   elem.innerHTML = txt
})
```

```html
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/a</div>
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/b</div>
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/c</div>
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/d</div>
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/e</div>
<div class="example">1/2/3/4/5/f</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think OP is using inputs, so "innerHTML" wouldn't work for him. I think he meant to use the "value" property, but I might be wrong.